# The content doesn't show to preview when using QPrintPreviewDialog

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt version 4.8.4 on Window 7. I don’t have conditions to test this issue on another platform such as Mac, Linux… and I use the following code to preview content

```
void DemoClass::on_btnOK_clicked()
{
    QPrinter printer;
    printer.setResolution(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
    printer.setFullPage(true);

    QPrintPreviewDialog *printPreview = new QPrintPreviewDialog(&printer);
    connect(printPreview, SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter*)), this, SLOT(print(QPrinter*)));

    printPreview->setWindowTitle("Preview Dialog");
    Qt::WindowFlags flags(Qt::WindowTitleHint);
    printPreview->setWindowFlags(flags);
    printPreview->exec();
}

void DemoClass::print(QPrinter *printer)
{
    QPainter painter(printer);
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing |
                       QPainter::TextAntialiasing |
                       QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true);

    painter.drawText(100, 100, "Hello World! 123");
}
```

On pushing the OK button, this dialog appears:

[image: Cannot show the preview content]

As you see, **the page is blank**. The page doesn’t contain any content. Then I click the page setup button on the preview dialog and this appears:

[image: Cannot show the preview content]

…without changing anything, I click OK and then the preview becomes **correct**:

[image: Cannot show the preview content]

I really don’t understand what the reason is. How can I show the content correctly without changing page setup?

Do you have any solutions?

***P/S:*** I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135545/qprintpreviewdialog-incorrect-preview) which is similar with my issue. The author recommend to use `QPageSetupDialog` object and I tried different ways. But I still didn't solve the problem because I am a newbie in Qt.

Comment: it may be because of you do not use "painter.end()" and when you come to page setup painter.end might be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in setting the high resolution to the printer, which is, according to documentation, 1200 dpi. Removing the following line

```
printer.setResolution(QPrinter::HighResolution);
```

makes the text appear in the preview window.
Since you try to set the high resolution, I think you also need to scale your painter accordingly, so that it correspond to the view/page size.

Comment: That is the answer I need. Finally I have solved my issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is probably because QPrinter::setResolution expects an actual DPI, while QPrinter::HighResolution is an enum you pass into the QPrinter constructor to tell it to use the highest supported DPI.